# What is the difference between vwapy and vwagy difference

Tags: adr

What is the difference between vwagy and vwapy they are unsponsored adr's but can find information what is the difference?

Comment: 30 seconds of Googling suggests that VWAGY is ordinary shares and VWAPY is preferred shares.

Answer (score 1):

Voting rights w VWAGY, no voting rights w VWAPY